# Real time update content from database

Tags: php, database, real-time

I have beggining php this week so i don´t have experience. I want to know how i can make real time update (without refreshing page) data from a database.
If i have this database:

```
section  | himidity

1        | 5

2        | 40   

3        | 30

4        | 25

5        | 26
```

How can i update the value in real time since the humidity is always changing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found a code that update each second but only refresh the date:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
tt=display_c();
}
</script>


<body onload=display_ct();>
update<span id='ct' ></span>
```

What i have to change to give the update from the database?

Thanks